# Шаблон Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Есть у меня проект на андроид студио с некоторым количеством активити. Они полностью готовы, работают. Решил сделать навигацию между ними при помощи встроенного шаблона Navigation Drawer Activity. Начал изучать эту тему и выяснил что для осуществления задуманного нужно использовать Fragment (Blank). Можно ли как то использовать Empty активити для Navigation Drawer, и если нет то как лучше поступить?

```
public class index extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

     //blankFragmentDeleted = new BlankFragmentDeleted();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.index, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentClass = Main2Activity.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Вставляем фрагмент, заменяя текущий фрагмент
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cont, fragment).commit();
    // Выделяем выбранный пункт меню в шторке
    item.setChecked(true);
    // Выводим выбранный пункт в заголовке
    setTitle(item.getTitle());


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: вы в обработке выбора пункта меню можете писать что угодно, хоть старт новой активити.

Comment: Приложение вылетает в таком случае "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.witryna, PID: 27967
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference"

Comment: дак код покажите ...

Comment: ваш fragment возвращает null

Comment: написать что то типа Fragment fragment = new Fragment(); ?